# lose the last character of a string with regex in pandas

Tags: python, regex, pandas

So I only want a certain part of a string from in a dataframe. But I can't find a solution to leave out the ]

My regex is `(?P<error>(?<=-.).*?(?=\s[^]]))`

The dataframe string: `[app.py:1891 - log_exception] Exception on /batch_request [POST]`

And this gives me: `"log_exception]"`, but I only want `"log_exception"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your regex to:

```
(?P<error>(?<=-.).*?(?=[\s\]]))
```

In your regex the positive lookahead contains:

- `\s` - a space, and then
- `[^]]` - a single char other than `]`.

Just this sequence (a space and `E`) occurs after the `]`.

Comment: Thanks, this helpt as well!

Answer (score 1):

```
(?P<error>(?<=-.).*?(?=\]))
```

You can use this.
See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/A1QKj3/1

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
df['colname'].str.extract(r'-\s*(?P<error>[^][]+)]\s')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/D1LS8Q/1)

The regex matches

- `-` - a hyphen
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(?P<error>[^][]+)` - Group "error": 1 or more chars other than `[` and `]`
- `]` - a `]` char
- `\s` - a whitespace